# Strength of key pair

Tags: authentication, cryptography, asymmetric

I'm trying to find a basis for comparing key pair based authentication with password based authentication, and their relative resistance to guessing / brute force attacks.

I appreciate that a user-chosen password will likely have a lot less entropy than a random one - has there been any attempt to measure the difference?

For a brute force attack, I expect the cost of generating a key pair will be much higher than for generating a password, but is there much of a difference in the cost for validating the key pair compared with validating a password?

A password of a given length could potentially be any string of characters of that length, so a simple incrementing counter converted to a string of character codes would give every possible password. However the same does not apply to a key pair - indeed the number of possible values appears to be very sparse. Are there any estimates of how many key pairs exist for a given algorithm / key size?

Comment: You appear to be thinking only of RSA, which is slightly sparse; DSA/DH/IES/etc and the EC variants use _any_ (randomly-chosen) number in (1,order) as the privatekey, albeit a larger image as the publickey. For currently-popular 2048-bit (2-prime) RSA, the prime number theorem tells us the number of 2048-bit semiprimes is about 2^2046 / ln(2^1024)^2 which is about 10^1400, whereas the number of atoms in the universe is much less than 10^100, so you would need to replace every atom with an entire other universe _more than 14 times_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A start would be comparing [password entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Entropy_as_a_measure_of_password_strength) to symmetric key size. A random password of 13 characters has approximately 80 bits of entropy, thus is comparable in security as a 1024 bit RSA key pair.

However, this is mostly theoretical since users typically choose insecure passwords, while key pairs are almost always random.

I would say key pairs always offer better security against brute force, but whether they should be used in your situation depends on other factors.

[image: table]

Comment: This looks exactly like the answer I was looking for to the third part of my question - have you got a URL for the table above? Is this backed up by any jutification?

Comment: [For anyone](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6219) wondering why ECC key size is 2 * symmetric key size _except_ for 521.

Comment: @symcbean: https://www.keylength.com and links there; compare to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3766 also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/how-big-an-rsa-key-is-considered-secure-today and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/how-to-estimate-the-time-needed-to-crack-rsa-encryption/

Comment: @AndrolGenhald More directly, these are the bit sizes of the P-X NIST curves, and P-521 (identical to secp521r1) is the one with the highest bit count. Actually, a 512 bit curve would have the recommended security strength, so in that sense the table is incorrect. Maybe it was a stab to the brainpool specs, which does specify a 512 bit prime curve.

Answer (score 1):

To answer just the second question:

Technically "validation" of a key pair would require less overhead as explained in the following link: [RSA Brute Force](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33510/how-to-check-that-you-got-the-right-key-when-brute-forcing-an-encryption)

However just to clarify, it is not merely much more difficult, but likely that the heat death of the universe will occur before anyone would be able to obtain a key pair through a brute force method as explained here:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/how-much-computing-resource-is-required-to-brute-force-rsa

Not to say it can't be cracked of course, simply that this method of cracking is actually impossible.

Comment: @symcbean In rereading your question I believe I may have misunderstood what it was asking.  Could you clarify if this answers your second question or should I remove it?

Comment: I was specifically wondering about the effort, I guess its a silly question if people are picking sensible sized keys - I did consider that if a vulnerability emerged in the underlying algorithms, the effort of brute forcing might be significantly reduced. On reflection making choices on such a hypthetical and therefore unquantifiable situation is not a very pratical approach. Thank you for highlighting this.